# How to populate Bullet points in a Table cell in PPT Slide using python-pptx

Tags: python-pptx

I am trying to populate some values in a PPT Slide which has a table.
These values are in a list and want to show them as bullet points.
I am using python-pptx module for coding.
How can I do this?

I tried the code below which creates a slide from an existing layout which has a Table placeholder.

```
# Insert and populate the Table in the slide.
def populate_table():

    table_ph = slide.placeholders[12]
    graphic_frame = table_ph.insert_table(rows = 2, cols = 3)
    table = graphic_frame.table

    # Get a handle to text_frame to a particular cell
    tf = table.cell(1,2).text_frame
    p = tf.paragraphs[0]
    p.text = "Bullet 1"
    p.level = 1

    # Second Bullet value
    p = tf.add_paragraph()
    p.text = "Bullet 2"
    p.level = 1

    # Third Bullet value
    p = tf.add_paragraph()
    p.text = "Bullet 3"
    p.level = 1
```

The Above code is printing/showing the 3 strings as 3 lines in the cell(1,2) but they are not appearing as bullet points.

Note: Running the same code in a text shape placeholder is displaying the bullet points.

```
shape = slide.placeholders[0] # This is a text placeholder.
tf = shape.text_frame
```

Can anyone please guide me what am i doing wrong? How can I show bullet points in a table cell?

Comment: Hi, I'm trying to do the same, did you make any progress?