# Using python-pptx to create table cells with bulleted text

Tags: python-pptx

I am looking to create a table with some of the cells to contain bullet points (not plain text) and I couldn't find any help even after a lot of internet search. There is a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56878078/how-to-populate-bullet-points-in-a-table-cell-in-ppt-slide-using-python-pptx) raised nearly 1.5 yrs ago but with no responses to that question. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

From what I know bullet points are not yet directly supported by python-pptx. But there is a workaround. You can change the Slide Master Style so that the 2nd level is a bullet point. Now if you add text to a cell, and format it, you can add `level = 1` to the paragraph object. Have only done this on a text placeholder, but should work the same on any Shape objects.

Comment: Thanks for your response, derchris. However, in my case i needed this to be done to text within a cell of a table. Eventually did that part manually.